# Receiving error: no alternatives for mozilla-flashplugin

Tags: google-chrome, flash

First of all, I am very new to this and a lot of it looks like martian to me, so please take that into consideration when answering.

I am trying to install chrome but i got dependency error... I check around and saw that using the command  `sudo apt-get install -f` might fix the issue.  This is what I got when i ran it:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libgnomecups1.0-1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.233ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-flashplugin.
dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: so did you run `sudo apt-get autoremove` from terminal? What version of Ubuntu are you using and how are you trying to install Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

my advice run from Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove (if necessary)
```

after install Ubuntu Tweak:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

start `Ubuntu Tweak` going to Dash panel type `ubuntu-tweak`, once it opened click on a tab `apps` and then navigate to `browser` there you'll be presented with browser bundles available like Google Chrome offered in 3 ways `stable`, `unstable` and `beta` choose and tick the one you desire to run a `stable` release bundle or experience new features in `beta` or `alfa` release depends on you.

P.S.

You can also find a lot of interesting stuff in Ubuntu Tweak

Answer (score 0):

No other method won't work other than the `dpkg --force` option.Try the below command to remove the `flashplugin-installer` forcely,

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq flashplugin-installer
```

Then run the below command to autoremove the no longer required packages,

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now install `flashplugin-installer` by running,

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```